# Put an Echo inside the For Loop

Tags: php, list, printing, syntax, list-comprehension

I have seen all similar answers and they all tell us the same thing. But You do need a loop inside echo like a date selector with time?
Is there a nice way with just 1 For Loop to do all date & time?

Edit:
I am so sorry, my code indeed is terrible and functions just didn't cross my mind. I'll keep that in mind, all perfect answers thankyou!

Comment: Please take care to format code before posting. You might want to check out functions in answer to your question and maybe take a read up on computer programming as functions are one of the basics of computer programming.

Comment: Sorry, It never crossed my mind to use them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create function and then use it:

```
function options($start, $end, $name, $label = '') {
  echo "{$label}<select name='$name'><option></option>";
  for($x = $start; $x <= $end; $x++) { echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>"; }
  echo "</select>";
}

options(1, 31, 'day', 'Date:');
options(1, 12, 'month', '/');
options(2012, 2022, 'year', '/');
options(0, 23, 'hour', 'Time:');
options(0, 59, 'minute', ':');
```

Answer (score 2):

That's why functions have been created...

```
function displayOptions($start, $end)
{
    // insert here some tests on start and end

    for($x = $start ; $x <= $end ; $x++) {
        echo "<option value=\"$x\">$x</option>";     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function:

```
// $min contain start value
// $max contain end value
function create_list($min, $max) {
    echo "<select name=''><option></option>";
    for($x=$min;$x<=$max;$x++) { echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>"; }
    echo '</select>';
}

// call function as many time as you want to generate selectbox

create_list(1,31);
create_list(1,12);
create_list(2012,2022);
create_list(1,24);
create_list(1,59);
```